# Opencart .htaccess config issue

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I know there was similar issues but was unable to resolve the problem I've been having.

I am using Opencart 1.5.5.1. We recently updated the website so all the links are completely different so I have 301 redirected a very large number of links. The problem is, they aren't working.

This is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 
# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.
# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none

RewriteRule ^downloads.asp$ http://www.example.com/downloads [R=301,L]

#301 redirect
Redirect 301 /onlinestore http://mywebsite.com.au
Redirect 301 /gallery.html http://mywebsite.com.au
Redirect 301 /Images/getaflatstomachoct2012.pdf http://mywebsite.com.au
Redirect 301 /onlinestore/all-products/allvia-melatonin-3-cream-57g http://mywebsite.com.au
Redirect 301 /aboutus.html http://mywebsite.com.au/about_us
Redirect 301 /meetus.html http://mywebsite.com.au/about_us
Redirect 301 /mission.html http://mywebsite.com.au/about_us
Redirect 301 /articleselectprotein.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs
Redirect 301 /enewsletters.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/april2013/april2013.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/june2010/enewsletterjune2010.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/june2013/june2013.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/october2012/october2012.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs
Redirect 301 /proteintablelarge.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/november2011/november2011.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs/christmas-survival-guide.html
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/march2011/march2011.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs/digestion-boost-energy-recover-better-be-happier.html
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/february2011/february2011.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs/fat-loss-during-your-lunch-break.html
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/june2012/june2012.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs/living-healthier-by-alkalising-your-body-what-it-means-and-how-to-achieve-it..html
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/august2010/enewsletteraugust2010.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs/marathon-triathlon-and-endurance-supplementation-guide.html
Redirect 301 /articletop10fattips.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs/psn-s-top-10-fat-loss-tips.html
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/september2010/enewsletterseptember2010.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs/psn-s-top-10-fat-loss-tips.html
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/march2012/march2012.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs/q-a-we-answer-frequently-asked-questions.html
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/may2012/may2012.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs/supplement-packs-for-your-goal.html
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/november2010/enewsletternovember2010.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs/supplement-packs-for-your-goal.html
Redirect 301 /enewsletters/july2011/july2011.html http://mywebsite.com.au/blogs/zma-better-sleep-sex-recovery-and-more.html
Redirect 301 /contactus.html http://mywebsite.com.au/contact
Redirect 301 /maplarge.pdf http://mywebsite.com.au/contact
Redirect 301 /benefits.html http://mywebsite.com.au/membership-terms-and-conditions.html
Redirect 301 /memberform.html http://mywebsite.com.au/membership-terms-and-conditions.html
Redirect 301 /terms.html http://mywebsite.com.au/membership-terms-and-conditions.html
Redirect 301 /onlinestore/accessories-1/all-accessories?page=1 http://mywebsite.com.au/accessories
Redirect 301 /onlinestore/accessories-1/all-accessories?page=2 http://mywebsite.com.au/accessories
Redirect 301 /onlinestore/accessories-1/all-accessories?page=3 http://mywebsite.com.au/accessories
Redirect 301 /onlinestore/accessories-1/all-accessories?page=4 http://mywebsite.com.au/accessories
Redirect 301 /onlinestore/accessories-1/all-accessories/advanced-fitness-manta-ray http://mywebsite.com.au/accessories
```

The redirects continue. So the issue is:

-when you go to original address:
http://www.mywebsite.com.au/onlinestore/accessories-1/all-accessories/advanced-fitness-manta-ray

-it should redirect you to here:
http://mywebsite.com.au/accessories

-but it goes here:
route=onlinestore/accessories-1/all-accessories/advanced-fitness-manta-ray">http://mywebsite.com.au/accessories-1/all-accessories/advanced-fitness-manta-ray?*route*=onlinestore/accessories-1/all-accessories/advanced-fitness-manta-ray

So the issue is, it goes to the correct new site, but then adds **?*route*=** followed by the original url.

I have tried to get support but have had no success. If I can get any support at all, I would be very grateful.

Regards,
Helen

Answer (score 0):

You need to place all of your redirect commands before the `RewriteEngine On` line, otherwise they will not get executed